# Google+ photo in Qgis

Tags: qgis, geotag

I'm trying to use the kml file in qgis but only the html code is being stored in the attribute table. How to show the uploaded image(Google+) in qgis. It works fine in Google earth.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you'll have to save the files to your local machine and then [follow this tutorial here.](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/geotagphotos/wiki)

Comment: This could be considered a link only answer which is generally discouraged. You should at least summarize the information contained at the link within your answer, as links can go dead in the future and render the answer useless.